# How to insert calculated the data and detect prompt window text into new table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 table in my db one the details and result. I display all the data from details table and do some calculation of data and displayed it.

I set a button to add the value(calculation value)into the result table and need to give a name of a result(i use popup window) But it not work.

**My problem is how can i detect the name in php and insert it in by using php?
Besides that i also cannot add result in result table**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script> 
function enterMonth() 
    {
    window.prompt("Please enter month and year of result","(mm-yyyy)");
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

<p>
  <?php

    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=gcmes", "root", "");
    $sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM details");

    echo"<table class='info' align='center'>";
    echo"<tr><td width='5'><b>Item</b></td>
    <td width='75'><b>Category</b></td>
    <td width='160'><b>Job</b></td>
    <td width='45'><b>Frequency</b></td>
    <td width='4' align='center'><b>H1</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H2</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H3</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H4</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H5</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H6</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H7</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H8</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H9</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H10</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H11</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H12</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H13</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H14</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H15</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H16</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H17</b></td>
    <td width='4'><b>H18</b></td>
    <tr>";
    foreach($sql as $row) {
    $Item = $row["Item"];
    $Category = $row["Category"];
    $Job = $row["Job"];
    $Frequency = $row["Frequency"];
    $Hole1 = $row["Hole1"];
    $Hole2 = $row["Hole2"];
    $Hole3 = $row["Hole3"];
    $Hole4 = $row["Hole4"];
    $Hole5 = $row["Hole5"];
    $Hole6= $row["Hole6"];
    $Hole7 = $row["Hole7"];
    $Hole8 = $row["Hole8"];
    $Hole9 = $row["Hole9"];
    $Hole10 = $row["Hole10"];
    $Hole11 = $row["Hole11"];
    $Hole12 = $row["Hole12"];
    $Hole13 = $row["Hole13"];
    $Hole14 = $row["Hole14"];
    $Hole15 = $row["Hole15"];
    $Hole16 = $row["Hole16"];
    $Hole17 = $row["Hole17"];
    $Hole18 = $row["Hole18"];

    echo'
        <tr>
            <td>' . $Item . '</td>
            <td>' . $Category . '</td>
            <td>' . $Job . '</td>
            <td>' . $Frequency . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole1 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole2 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole3 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole4 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole5 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole6 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole7 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole8 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole9 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole10 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole11 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole12 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole13 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole14 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole15 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole16 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole17 . '</td>
            <td align=center>' . $Hole18 . '</td>
        </tr>
    ';

    }

    ?>   
    <?php
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','gcmes');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT Job FROM details";

if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  $totalmarks= ($rowcount*5);
  }

    $add = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT SUM(Hole1),SUM(Hole2),SUM(Hole3),SUM(Hole4),SUM(Hole5),SUM(Hole6),SUM(Hole7),SUM(Hole8),SUM(Hole9),SUM(Hole10),SUM(Hole11),SUM(Hole12),SUM(Hole13),SUM(Hole14),SUM(Hole15),SUM(Hole16),SUM(Hole17),SUM(Hole18) from `details`');
  while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($add))
  {
    $mark1=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole1)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' ');
    $mark2=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole2)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' ');  
    $mark3=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole3)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' '); 
    $mark4=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole4)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' '); 
    $mark5=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole5)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' '); 
    $mark6=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole6)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' '); 
    $mark7=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole7)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' '); 
    $mark8=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole8)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' '); 
    $mark9=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole9)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' '); 
    $mark10=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole10)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' '); 
    $mark11=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole11)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' '); 
    $mark12=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole12)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' '); 
    $mark13=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole13)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' '); 
    $mark14=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole14)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' '); 
    $mark15=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole15)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' ');
    $mark16=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole16)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' ');
    $mark17=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole17)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' ');
    $mark18=number_format(((($row1['SUM(Hole18)'])/$totalmarks)*100), 2, '.', ' ');
?>

  <tr>
    <th colspan="4">Total (%)</th>
    <th><?php echo $mark1 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark2 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark3 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark4 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark5 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark6 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark7 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark8 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark9 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark10 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark11 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark12 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark13 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark14 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark15 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark16 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark17 ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $mark18 ?></th>
  </tr>

  <?php } 
  echo"</table>";
  ?>
</p>
<p><div align="center"><form action="ResultHole.php" method="post"><input type="submit"  onClick="enterMonth()" value="Submit" name="Submit_btn" id="Submit_btn"></form></div></p>
<?php 
// Create connection
$conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','gcmes');
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    if(isset($_POST['Submit_btn'])){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO result (date,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,h7,h8,h9,h10,h11,h12,h13,h14,h15,h16,h17,h18) VALUES(?,'$mark1','$mark2','$mark3','$mark4','$mark5','$mark6','$mark7','$mark8','$mark9','$mark10','$mark11','$mark12','$mark13','$mark14','$mark15','$mark16','$mark17','$mark18')";

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('New record created successfully');
    window.location.href = 'ResultHole.php';
    </script>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**What is the problem? Anyone can help? Thank you!**